Providing extra credentials in Trino driver for SQLTools extension for VS Code
I am using Trino driver for SQLTools extension in Visual Studio Code.
I've connected to my corporate database (Hive and Greenplum with Postgresql), but some schemas in Greenplum DB require special privileges to access.
This was solved in DBeaver IDE by specifying "extraCredentials" in Driver Properties window
DBeaver Driver Properties
I've found .json file with settings, but I don't know where and how to put it
Trino driver in SQLTools settings .json file
Where can I add this setting in Trino driver in SQLTools extension?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
